# CMake Precompiled Headers not including correctly for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

So I've recently started using the "new" `target_precompile_headers` command for CMake to generate and include my precompiled headers.
But for some reason it doesn't seem to work at all the way I want it.

I do understand that the usage of this command is to provide the list of headers to include in your pch and that CMake itself generates the actual pch. This seem to work just fine as I can see the pchs generated for each config & project in my solution.

However looking at the project properties, and more specifically looking at the .cpp properties the /FI command is always empty, which means no files are force included.

This also means that none of my cpp catches that I am using pch at all and my compile fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be wrong?

```
// Example of a CMakeLists.txt which defines a static lib using PCH
file(GLOB ALL_SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp" "*.h")
    
add_library(MyLib STATIC ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES})
target_precompile_headers(MyLib PRIVATE MyHeader.h)
```

Below you see my own lib created with the snippet above. As you can see, no Forced Include file is added, thus no cpp files gets the PCH included.
[image]

Comment: Please, do not use **images** for the code. This is discouraged by Stack Overflow. Instead, copy-paste your code into the question post as **text**.

Comment: Which version of cmake? Have you tried clearing your build directory and re-generating? Please provide a [mre] as text not images

Comment: @AlanBirtles
Sorry for the images, I've updated the question with an example of what I am doing.
My CMake version is 3.21 (latest binaries), but I've had the problem ever since I started using CMake which was 3.17.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround: Adding the compiler option manually...

```
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(YourProject PRIVATE "/FI${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${PROJECT_NAME}.dir/$<CONFIG>/cmake_pch.hxx")
endif()
```

(Currently using Cmake 3.24.1 with `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)` in the file)